# Software to monitor file copy events

Tags: monitoring, network-monitor, filesystems

I've looked into filesystemwatcher/file system filter drivers... none of this does exactly what I want.  I want to monitor a source file system (NAS) and when a copy command is executed on one of the files from a remote machine I want to log this.  Is there a shell extension or software that can accomplish this task?